# Can't install systemd-boot

Tags: arch-linux, boot, boot-loader, systemd-boot

I found an SSD that I thought I'd lost and decided to do try an Arch Linux build.  I've got an ASUS mobo with the proprietary UEFI and the machine was bought from a store with a Windows license (unsure if that will affect booting so I thought I'd bring it up).

Firstly, here's an `lsblk`:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN    RM    SIZE    RO    TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
sdc       8:32      0   111.8G    0    disk
|_sdc1    8:33      0     512M    0    part    /boot
|_sdc2    8:34      0      12G    0    part    [SWAP]
|_sdc3    8:35      0    99.3G    0    part    /
```

And a `cat /etc/fstab`:

```
# /dev/sdc1 UUID=<sdc1_uuid>
UUID=<sdc1_uuid>     /boot  vfat    rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro    0 2

# /dev/sdc2 UUID=<sdc2_uuid>
UUID=<sdc2_uuid>      none  swap    defaults    0 0

# /dev/sdc3 LABLE=system
UUID=<sdc3_uuid>      /     ext4    rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1
```

And my device list item from `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbb103c57

Device    Boot    Start    End    Sectors    Size    Id    Type
/dev/sdc1 *        2048  1050623  1048576    512M     b    W95 FAT32
/dev/sdc2       1050624 26241023 25190400     12G    83    Linux
/dev/sdc3      26241024 234440703 208199680  99.3G   83    Linux
```

I'm at the [Bootloader](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners'_guide#Boot_loader) step of the Arch Linux Beginner's Guide and thought that I needed to follow the [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot#EFI_boot) steps as well.  I *then* started reading the [automount](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFISTUB#Using_systemd) article, and thought about asking where the kernel and `initramfs` files that are mentioned in step 4 are located, but after reading I'm unsure of if `systemd-boot` will attempt to replace the UEFI firmware I've already got, or if it's required for my UEFI firmware to automount my `boot` partition and subsequently communicate with my `SWAP` and `/` partitions as well?

Or do I not need to worry about it because I've already designated a boot partition and ran the following?

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/boot
# mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/boot
```

If I've already ran the above and finish without bothering with the boot loader, will I simply be able to select the SSD from my UEFI boot options (as I'm intending) because I've already got a designated boot partition formatted and ran `pacstrap`?  Or will it be unbootable without a live Linux disc so I can mount the partitions manually?

Or am I completely misguided?

---

I've tried to forgo the Boot loader steps and run `bootctl --path=/dev/sdc1 install`, but get the following error:

```
File system "/dev/sdc1" is not a FAT EFI System Partition (ESP) file system.
```

If all of my disk utilities are showing that the requirements are met (i.e. it has `/boot`, is `fat32` formatted, and shows as `vfat` in my `fstab`), why am I getting an error that says the disk isn't the format that the other tools show that it is?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to create filesystems on your partitions

Answer (score 0):

There is one more requirement for the EFI System Partition: it should have type EF00 or GUID C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B. This GUID is the type of the partition, a fixed value, not the GUID of the partition itself.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_System_Partition